# Render method from class with node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, async-await

I have a class with methods which should give me domains of an API.
That also works so far. But if I want to render it with Node Express I get an array with 1.2.3. without the domain name.

I think my problem is located at async await?!

Here is a snippet from my class method:

```js
class ISPConfig {
    constructor(base_url, options) {
        this.base_url = base_url;
        this.options = options;
    }

    async _call() {
        ... // gives me the sessionId
    }

    async getDataByPrimaryId(ispFunction, param) {
        try {
        const results = await axios.post(this.base_url + ispFunction, {
            session_id: await this._call(),
            primary_id: param
        });
        return await results.data.response;
        //console.log(results.data.response);
        } catch (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

And her a snippet from my app.js:

```js
const renderHome = (req, res) => {
    let domains = [],
        message = '';
    let a = new ispwrapper.ISPConfig(BASE_URL, OPTIONS)
    a.getDataByPrimaryId('sites_web_domain_get', { active: 'y' })
        .then(response => {
            for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                domains = response[i]['domain'].domains;
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            message = 'Error when retriving domains from ISPApi';
        })
        .then(() => {
            res.render('home', { // 'home' template file for output render
                title: 'ISPConfig',
                heading: 'Welcome to my ISPConfig Dashboard',
                homeActive: true,
                domains,
                message
            });
        });
};
```

With push(domains) I get on the HTML page only 1.2.3.

Which corresponds exactly to the three active domains of my API. But just without the domain names. :(

But if I output in for loop console.log(response[i]['domain'].domains) I get all domains with names in console.

Does anyone see my mistake?

**Here is my Solution:**

```
const renderHome = async (req, res) => {
let domain = [],
    message = '';
try {
    let a = new ispwrapper.ISPConfig(BASE_URL, OPTIONS);
    const response = await a.getDataByPrimaryId('sites_web_domain_get', { active: 'y' });

    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
         domain.push(response[i].domain);
    }
} catch(err) {
    message = 'Error when retriving domains from ISPApi';
} finally {
    res.render('home', { // 'home' template file for output render
        title: 'ISPConfig',
        heading: 'Welcome to my ISPConfig Dashboard',
        homeActive: true,
        domain,
        message
    });
}
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making your route async too like:

```
const renderHome = async (req, res) => {
  let domains = [],
      message = '';
  try {
    let a = new ispwrapper.ISPConfig(BASE_URL, OPTIONS)
    const response = await a.getDataByPrimaryId('sites_web_domain_get', { active: 'y' })

    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
      domains.push(response[i].domain);
    }
  } catch(err) {
    message = 'Error when retriving domains from ISPApi';
  } finally {
    res.render('home', { // 'home' template file for output render
      title: 'ISPConfig',
      heading: 'Welcome to my ISPConfig Dashboard',
      homeActive: true,
      domains,
      message
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my first idea, too. Because the class is also written in the async / await syntax.

Unfortunately this only gives me 3 x undefined in the for loop.

Comment: Could you link the `response` result to some fiddle

Comment: Inside the loop:
undefined
undefined
undefined

outside the loop:
undefined

Comment: In the `response` you've linked, none of the object have `domain.domains` property. In every single one of them `domain` is just a string. Update answer to reflect that. check out

Answer (score 0):

Yes ok the undefined is no problem anymore. But how do I get the domains displayed on the HTML page? The call is grey.

[image]